# unable to compile anything after installing cpr library #

Tags: c++, programming, g++, arm64

```
sudo g++ -o /usr/local/bin/t1 '/home/ubuntu/Desktop/test1.cpp'
```

I am encountering an error while attempting to compile any cpp file, regardless of which one it is. The error message reads:

```
"as: error while loading shared libraries: libcpr.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory."
```

Initially, I attempted to export the library's location to the environment variable by using the following command:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/lib/
```

Although this approach seemed effective at first, it ultimately proved to be unsuccessful.

Comment: Why are compiling as `root`? Why are you dropping your compiled binary straight into `/usr/local/bin/`? Don't you test it? `strip` it? Bad Development Practice. Build it elsewhere, not as `root`. Read `man sudo sudoers`.

Comment: @waltinator i try to compile without root but i am facing a new eror:              /usr/bin/ld: /usr/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-gnu/11/../../../aarch64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: in function `_start':
(.text+0x1c): undefined reference to `main'
/usr/bin/ld: (.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: I don't see libcpr.so in any of the Ubuntu repositories for any architecture. Are you using a non-Ubuntu g++ toolchain?

Comment: ... for the error mentioned in your comment, that's telling you that there is no `main` function in your .cpp file

Comment: @steeldriver there is a main. And i am encountering these error in every file i am trying to compile.

Comment: @steeldriver these is the repository https://docs.libcpr.org/ that i installed. At first it works fine but now it does not.

Comment: I am thinking about resetting my operating system 